# How to delete a label for a kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I want delete label from a node or a pod by kubernetes API, my kubernetes version:1.24

```
kubectl get pod --show-labels | grep all-flow-0fbah
all-flow-0fbah      1/1     Running   2        9d      app=all-flow,op=vps1,version=1001
```

I use command as below:

```
 curl --request PATCH --header "Content-Type:application/json-patch+json" http://10.93.78.11:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/all-flow-0fbah --data '{"metadata":{"labels":{"a":"b"}}}'
```

But this doesn't work. Return message as below:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "the server responded with the status code 415 but did not return more information",
  "details": {},
  "code": 415
}
```

Then I change the curl header like this :

```
curl --request PATCH --header "Content-Type:application/merge-patch+json" http://10.93.78.11:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/all-flow-0fbah --data '{"meadata":{"labels":{"op":"vps3"}}}'
```

It not delete label but add a new label to that pod.
So is there any one can tell me how to delete a label for a pod like use command :

```
kubectl label pod all-flow-0fbah key-
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As workhardcc posted in a comment, the way to do this is

```
curl -k -v -XPATCH -H "Accept: application/json, /" -H "Content-Type: application/strategic-merge-patch+json" 10.10.10.10:443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pds/all-flow-946y0 --data '{"metadata":{"labels":{"$patch": "delete", "app":"all-flow"}}}'
```

Comment: Is the full syntax of this “stategic merge patch” somewhere documented?

Comment: For a description of how the merge works, see https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/strategic-merge-patch.md. The syntax is as posted above but the data you pass in should look like the json representation of the object, which can be determined by running `kubectl get pod all-flow-0fbah -o json`.

Answer (score 17):

I think this is the straightforward way to do that, which I found easier:

```sh
kubectl label pod <pod-name> <label key>-
```

Answer (score 14):

Was looking for CLI command myself. Here is what worked for me:

```
kubectl patch pod <podname> --type=json -p='[{"op": "remove", "path": "/metadata/labels/somelabelkey"}]'
```

Answer (score 10):

The most convenient way is to use `kubectl edit pods all-flow-0fbah`. Just remove the label field in the editor.

See http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_edit/

Comment: It sounds like @workhardcc already found a way to use `kubectl` to remove the label and was trying to figure out how to do it in the raw api (using curl).

Comment: @RobertBailey you're right!, kubectl is easy, API seems more difficult.But I had already figure this problem out last week. Thanks !

Comment: If you have a solution, can you post it as an answer (to your question). Then other folks that run into the same issue will see that you figured out how to solve it.

Comment: @RobertBailey Sorry for my late reply:curl -k -v -XPATCH -H "Accept: application/json, /" -H "Content-Type: application/strategic-merge-patch+json" https://10.10.10.10:443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pds/all-flow-946y0 --data '{"metadata":{"labels":{"$patch": "delete", "app":"all-flow"}}}'

Answer (score 5):

In additions to answers above, it's worth mentioning that if you use JSON Patch to remove remove a label/annotation with a slash (`/`) or a tilde (`~`) in it you'll have to escape them as mentioned in http://jsonpatch.com:

- `~` becomes `~0`
- `/` becomes `~1`

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party, I  looked at `kubectl` code and found that they don't use this `op=remove` nonsense.

If you need to remove label you need to provide null as value (make sure it's not string value of "null" but rather null value)

```
request.go:1188] Request Body: {"metadata":{"labels":{"kube.com/code":null}}}
round_trippers.go:463] PATCH https://kube.com:6443/api/v1/namespaces/uat/resourcequotas/uat-resourcequota?fieldManager=kubectl-label
```