# How to delete a label by kubernetes api?

Tags: kubernetes, label

Usually, we delete a label like that 'kubectl label namespace namespace_name labelname-'

But I want to delete it by kubernetes api,  what should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you won't be able to delete the label but replace/rename it.

That might be doe using `patch` option which you can read about on [Update API Objects in Place Using kubectl patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/).

There is also several questions on Stack Overflow regarding this subject.
 - [How to delete a label for a kubernetes pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37481205/how-to-delete-a-label-for-a-kubernetes-pod)
 - [Kubernetes API: How to add/remove label from Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837008/kubernetes-api-how-to-add-remove-label-from-node)
- [How to remove a node label with kubernetes API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901432/how-to-remove-a-node-label-with-kubernetes-api)

Also here is an example how using a [Kubernetes Python Client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) you could patch the label:

```
from pprint import pprint
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_kube_config()
client.configuration.debug = True

api_instance = client.CoreV1Api()

body = {
    "metadata": {
        "labels": {
            "label-name": None}
        }
}

api_response = api_instance.patch_node("minikube", body)

print(api_response)
```

Answer (score 0):

Kubectl is internally calling REST API exposed by Kubernetes API Server to perform any operation including label deletion. But if you want to do it programmatically then you can use [kubernetes client libraries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) of different languages.

You can also curl the Kubernetes REST API yourself.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to delete label from node according to description here which I tested
https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/node_labels.py
Just set the value of Label to None then run the patch e.g

```
        for key in delete_labels:
            if key in node_labels:
                node_labels[key]= None
        node.metadata.labels = node_labels
        api_instance.patch_node(node_name,node)
```